# Error converting json to type

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am using RestSharp and trying to put json to the server while I am getting this error:

> Error converting value
>   \"{\"Id\":\"1698\",\"IsActive\":true,\"Number\":\"301\",\"Name\":\"the
>   name\"..... to type...

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.PUT);
request.AddJsonBody(json);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I have trie4d to make a server trip with standard webclient for the raw json without any success. Any ideeas? Or would '\"' cause any problems?

Comment: Could you please share sample json?

Comment: What is the `json` variable data type?  It should be a POCO not a string.

Comment: Well the problem in this case is that I am not provided with a model. So basically my best option is to handcraft a model? Althoug I thought it would be fine as working with json as strings due to standard...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with replaciing \" with '